# How can save a cookie response from the web service?

Tags: java, cookies

I've used `SOAPConnection` to invoke the service, the problem is the web service returns a cookie in response, how can i preserve that cookie for further calls??

```
SOAPConnectionFactory sfc = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection connection = sfc.createConnection();
        String text = new String(
                Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\abhinav.malviya\\workspace\\TestWeb\\src\\SOAP.xml")),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        SOAPMessage sm = getSoapMessageFromString(text);

        URL endpoint = new URL("http://URL/ProSightWS/psPortfoliosSecurity.asmx");
        SOAPMessage response = connection.call(sm, endpoint);

        printMessage(response);

        System.out.println(response.getContentDescription());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you use following code to create a cookie:

```
 BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) Port;
     Map<String,Object> requestContext = bindingProvider.getRequestContext();
     Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
     List<String> cookies = new ArrayList<String>();
     cookies.add("SMSESSION=testCookie");
     requestHeaders.put("Cookie", cookies);
     requestContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, requestHeaders);
```